# How to do this query with Laravel query builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, query-builder

I'm trying to run this query in Laravel, and would like to do it with the query builder, so I can use the paginate() method. But I can't seem to figure out how to get this subquery going.

The raw query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT *
FROM `order_history`
WHERE `customer_id` = '05033'
AND `part_number` LIKE 'M%'
ORDER BY `shippingdate` DESC) history
GROUP BY `part_number`
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Are you wanting to use Fluent, or Eloquent?

Comment: Eloquent would be preferable, but Fluent is fine too. Will post some try-outs later.

Answer (score 0):

```
DB::table(order_history)->where(function($query)
                         {
                              $query->where('customer_id','=','05033')
                                    ->where('part_number','like','$m');
                         })
                         ->group('part_number')
                         ->paginate(10)
                         ->get();
```

should be correctish

Comment: Well, not really, After paginate() you don't have to do get(), but other than that, this will give me a query like: `"select * from order_history where (customer_id = '05033' and part_number like 'M%') group by part_number"` which is not what I need. I need a subquery for the 'FROM' clause